# How read Environment variable in solr.properties

Tags: docker, solr, docker-compose

I'm triying read a Environment Variable in a solr.properties file, the solr is running in a docker container and my docker-compose look:

```
solr:

  environment:
   - DB_NAME="xxxx"
```

My solr.properties is in /var/solr/ and i tried read de Environment Variable how:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${DB_NAME}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=false

jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${env.DB_NAME}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=false

jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/${env:DB_NAME}?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=false
```

I'm starting with Docker, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You access the environment variable with `${DB_NAME}`. Also pay attention that you need to replace `localhost` with the name of the database service if your database runs in a different container (is also a service in docker-compose.yml) than solr (as it should be).

Comment: yes I used the container name, but isn't work, any example o guide ? when I try index the documents an error ocurred... but if I put the name of the DB it's works !

Comment: Check the syntax in your declaration of the environment variables. You should use colon instead of equals. You can also run a shell inside the container and use 'env' to check how the variables look like